# JQuery code stops working after page loads when navigating indirectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm facing the following issue:
All code works properly unless I navigate to a page by copy-pasting the url, clicking on the mouse scroll wheel etc. If I use the site menu to navigate to a page by left-clicking on it, it works fine. 
So, when a page is loaded indirectly, some of my JQuery code stops working after the page has finished loading - so it actually works for a second or so, and then stops. If, e.g. a click on a button before the page has finished loading, the code will run. If I wait until the page has finished loading, it doesn't. 
Also, this doesn't happen to all code, just parts of it. I've tried to figure out why some of it works, and it might be (or not) that the code that stops working is the one directly using methods from plugins I've included, which isn't inside a click event (or maybe inside another function?).

Example of working code:

```
$(".pr-gallery img").click(function(){
    var gallery = $(this).attr("data-num");
    $(gallery.toString()).magnificPopup('open');
});
```

Here, even though there is the `magnificPopup` method, it works fine.

Example of non-working code:

```
$('#ctr-fixed-menu').drawer({
    align: 'right'
});
```

I load all code inside:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
       ...code...
    }); 

})(jQuery);
```

and have also tried `$(function(window)`,   `jQuery(window).load`, as well as encasing all code inside a function like so:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    function TestCall() {
        ...all code here...
    }

    window.onload=TestCall;
    });
})(jQuery)
```

none of which have worked. It might be something really simple but I've tried to solve it for a couple of weeks now and it's driving me crazy. Also, there are no error messages in the console.

Just to note that this is for a WordPress website, so I don't know whether there might be some type of conflict with the original theme code (lazy loading for example?).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless someone sees an obvious reason for your problem in the little code snippets you've posted, it will be very hard to work out what the problem is. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (but I have to admit it will be difficult to given a working example). Debugging complex pieces of code, with lots of events, is probably something you have to do yourself.

Comment: how have you added your script? in functions? and on what action? - I can't seem to find any reason that this shouldn't work, by the basis of your snippets

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: Probably the reason is this; some of your document ready function is interrupting the other codes outside of the $(document).ready. So if there is a link of the page please share and we may have a look to the devtool.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware You're right, of course, but I thought that including the whole code would make things more complicated, as it's quite a large piece of code.

Comment: @Stender No console errors. It's being added through functions.php, using `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' )`.

Comment: @GüneySaramalı There is a temporary link. I didn't want to add it as it'll be soon invalid; still, here it is: http://kostislighting.gr.185-29-25-225.citrine.gr/ .And maybe a good example of a page where part of the code works: http://kostislighting.gr.185-29-25-225.citrine.gr/ξενοδοχειακά-επαγγελματικά-έργα/

Comment: I see no difference, between opening in a new tab, and clicking the menu-  can you explain some more?

Comment: Depending on your browser, you can open up the console to see if there's any js/jquery errors. Eg. in chrome you can right click and press inspect element and then click the Console tab in the pop up window.

Comment: @Stender On this page: http://kostislighting.gr.185-29-25-225.citrine.gr/ you can see the icon "Game of lights" on the right changing colour when scrolling from a dark to alight area. This doesn't happen on "indirect" loading. Also, the left vertical menu expands when clicking on one of the arrows, while on "indirect" loading it doesn't; it just loads a new page as it would if no code existed.

Comment: @designtocode As mentioned, I haven't managed to detect any console errors.

Comment: super weird - It seems like your JS, from lighting.js is actually added, because your scroll function to show and hide `.home-menu-sand-link` is working fine - and your header wrapper is actually getting the attribute, that your JS is giving it, and it seems like your gallery is functioning as well.

Comment: @Stender Exactly. And the only difference I have found is that the code that works is the one where no methods are being called directly (though, as in the case of the gallery, calling them on "click" works fine). It's really frustrating.